Spark Error: ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.network.shuffledb.DBBackend
I am using spark-core_2.13 and spark-sql_2.13 3.4.2 version and getting Spark Error: ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.network.shuffledb.DBBackend while creating spark session.
i have tried all the spark-core version but shuffledb [ackage is not even present in jar.
